# BizTalk 2013 Admin Console not loading after installing CU 7 update

Tags: biztalk, tls1.2, biztalk-2013

We have currently update from BizTalk 2010 to 2013 and after that we have installed CU 7 update for TLS1.2 requirement. But as we install this CU 7 update of BizTalk 2013, the console is not able to load it gives Error with DB connection. And when we uninstall this update it works fine.

Can any know what is causing this issue. We have 2 BizTalk server , at first server it is working fine but in second server we are facing this issue.
I have tried all possible solution provide on the internet like changing .mof file. Checked the access right at DB level. But nothing seems to be working.

[image: screenshot of the error message]

Comment: Did you restart the whole server after installing the CU? Did you run the installer as administrator and turning all the hosts off before running the installer? Also check the installation log, it shows you the link after the CU finished updating, check for lines with 'error' in it.

Comment: We did check the setup log but could not find anything in the log. And yes all setup was executed with "Run as administration mode" .

Comment: And we also did a restart of machine.Removed complete biztalk. Installed fresh setup of 2013 and over that installed sql native and then CU7. As we install CU7 it is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/starting-and-stopping-the-wmi-service) service is probably not running anymore after the CU completed.

Comment: In the service list it is running. But when i tried to check it through "WBEMTEST"  by firing query to DB. It is giving the same error that it could not connect to DB, as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

On the page [Cumulative Update 7 for BizTalk Server 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/4094163) it has the following

> **Important**
>
> This update includes KB article [4091110 - Update adds support for TLS 1.2 protocol in BizTalk Server.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4091110)

On the page Support for TLS 1.2 protocol in BizTalk Server, it has

> You must make sure that the prerequisites that are mentioned in this article are available on the computer on which this update is being applied. The update will stop if this condition isn't met.
>
> **Prerequisites**
>
> SQL Server 2012 Native Client version 11 should be installed on all BizTalk Server systems before you apply this update. If the SQL Native Client is not installed before you apply cumulative update, the installation may not complete.

Comment: We have installed first this SQL server 2012 Native client and then only we have installed CU7 update.

Comment: Did you also install the SQL server 2012 Native client on the Database Servers?

Comment: No...If it is the issue with the SQL server then how the First Biztalk Server is able to connect and working fine?

Comment: And our Sql server is of version 2008 r2

Comment: I tried installting SQl native on DB server. Still same error :-(

Comment: Try repairing the BizTalk installation from the BizTalk installer after installing the CU.

Comment: Repairing is also been tried...still stuck. Tried adding the TL1.2 & TLS 1.1 in registry and disabling TL 1.0 , that too didnt worked.
Tried removing all the update which were not present in working server. still causing same effect.
It seems WMI is breaking everytime I run CU7.

Comment: @Rehana As 1 server did work, and the other doesn't, did you compare the list of Windows updates (and features) installed on both servers? You have to match them as close as possible.

Comment: @r3verse Tried your solution as wel. Made exact number of updates & feature as in working server, but dat too doesn't seems working. :(

Comment: Sounds like time to raise this as an issue with Microsoft.

Comment: @Rehana did you check if the network configuration also matches? Like subnet, ip range, firewall configurations?